# "How to fix: View in Fragment does only get updated the first time the Fragment is displayed"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have a containerView within a Fragment that has to be resized according to the screensize. For this reason I `view.post{}` in onViewCreated.

When navigating to the fragment for the first time, everything is fine and the view gets resized as intended. However, when I then navigate to another fragment and, after that, navigate to the first fragment again, it does not get resized anymore.

I have already tried to view.invalidate() inside view.post{} and tried to use a ViewTreeObserver, both delivered the same results.

This is my code:

```
    class Fragment : OtherFragment() {

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        view.post {
            val containerView = view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.container)
            Timber.d("${containerView.id}")
            val originalWidth = containerView.width
            containerView.layoutParams.width = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
            containerView.layoutParams.height = ((containerView.width / originalWidth).toFloat() * containerView.height).toInt()
            Timber.d("originalWidth: $originalWidth, displayWidth: ${Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels}")
            Timber.d("onViewCreated: posted to view")
        }
        Timber.d("onViewCreatedCalled!")
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
    }

}
```

The logs show that onViewCreated and view.post{} are called.
Also, originalWidth(1148) and displayWidth(1080) and the containerView.id have the same values with every iteration.

What prevents the view from updating its size when it is displayed the second time?

This is the code that handles the navigation from the MainActivity:

```
private fun changeFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction?.replace(R.id.placeholder, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction?.addToBackStack(null)
    fragmentTransaction?.commit()
}


  override fun onBackPressed() {
    handleBackPressed()
}


private fun handleBackPressed() {
   if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount != 0 || doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
       super.onBackPressed()
   } else {
       this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true
       Handler().postDelayed({ doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false }, 2000)
       Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_exit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code related to navigation from fragment

Comment: I added the navigation logic to the original post

Comment: This is becase , the first time fragment is created its onCreateView is getting called and every time you come from other fragment to this its onStart will be called only. Can you check what lifecycle methods are getting called and where are you resizing the view?

Comment: But the onViewCreated is called again when I navigate back to the Fragment - the `Timber.d("onViewCreatedCalled!")` aswell as the `Timber.d("onViewCreated: posted to view")` logs are shown every time I navigate to the fragment.